# Django - filter model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a field that is a list.
For example:

```
mymodel.sessions = [session1, session2]
```

I need a query to get all `mymodels` that `session1` is exist their sessions.

The model`s field looks like that

```
sessions = models.ForeignKey("Session", related_name="abstracts",
                                null=True, blank=True)
```

Thank you !

Comment: Is `sessions` a model field? Usually these kinds of relationships are expressing using a foreign key relationship, but that doesn't seem to be what's going on in your code.

Comment: yes it is:
sessions = models.ForeignKey("Session", related_name="abstracts",
                                    null=True, blank=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse lookups that go back along the foreign key to query for values in the related model.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(sessions__id=1)
```

That will filter all `MyModel`s that have a foreign key to a session with an `id` of 1.

For more information see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django docs for `filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter):

> `filter(**kwargs)`
>
> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.

You can filter on a ForeignKey relationship using the id, if you have it:

> The field specified in a lookup has to be the name of a model field. There’s one exception though, in case of a ForeignKey you can specify the field name suffixed with _id. In this case, the value parameter is expected to contain the raw value of the foreign model’s primary key.

In your instance, this would like the following:

```
mymodel.objects.filter(sessions_id=4)
```

If you want to filter on any other field in the Sessions model, simply use a double underscore with the field. Some examples:

```
mymodel.objects.filter(sessions__name='session1')
mymodel.objects.filter(sessions__name__contains='1')
```